# Javascript redirect method inside page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am looking for a nice way to redicrect in my page, after an Ajax request

If it succeeds I would like to transform the current uri (location.href)

```
http://my.domain.com/jm/app.html?application=test&keyword=pp&data=&enum=&end=
```

into

```
http://my.domain.com/jm/app.html#Results?application=test&keyword=pp&data=&enum=&end=
```

So adding #Results after uri path, but I would like to preserve the query string,
It's probably ugly to find a regex for that, and apply it to location.href

Is there a jquery method to just browsing inside page?
like

```
$.redirectTo("Results")
```

Comment: Why not just update `location.hash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location) property?

As a side note, this plugin has come in really useful for detecting a change in the hash, and then reacting on it. [jQuery hashchange](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) or [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/). They both provide good support for HTML5 pushState with a fallback for HTML4 browsers (using a hash similar to your example). jQuery BBQ has some [nice functions](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html) for manipulating the query string, as well.

Here's the basic idea (using History.js). On success, you update the location like this:

```
var newUrl = "/app.htmlapplication=test&keyword=pp&data=&enum=&end=";

// Make AJAX request ...

// On success
History.pushState({}, null, newUrl);
```

You will also want to implement a listener for state/hash change events. Using History.js, it looks something like this:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
    // The user probably hit the back button, do something...
});
```

I kept my examples pretty short, so give a quick look at the documentation for each plugin and see which one fits your project best.